# ScalaJS: How to convert String to String?

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

Let's assume I have a list of Strings: `List[String]`. And I want to convert it to the interoperable JavaScript array of JavaScript Strings: `js.Array[js.String]`. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of doing that is the following:
`myList.map(x => x: js.String).toArray`
This can be factored out in an implicit conversion if you need it more than once.

**Edit**: this answer is obsolete. See [@gzm0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812262/1829647).

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of Scala.js 0.5.x (current version as of this writing is 0.6.2), there is no difference anymore between `java.lang.String` and `js.String`. Hence you can do:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSConverters._ // Scala.js >= 0.5.4

val list: List[String] = ???
val jsList: js.Array[String] = list.toJSArray
```